# SQL query combine report from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have database of support tickets, they are separated in two tables, say `Incidents`, `Tasks`.
`Incidents` has fields `assigned_group`, `open_time`, `close_time`
`Tasks` has fields `assignment`, `issue_date`, `close_date` (same meaning, but different names)

Now what I need is to compile a report of the following structure for a specific time period:

```
Group | Total opened incidents + tasks | Total closed incidents + tasks)
```

Individual queries would look like this:

```
-- Q1: Total opened incidents
SELECT assigned_group, COUNT(*) FROM incidents WHERE open_time BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY assigned_group

-- Q2: Total closed incidents
SELECT assigned_group, COUNT(*) FROM incidents WHERE close_time BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY assigned_group

-- Q3: Total opened tasks
SELECT assignment, COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE issue_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY assignment

-- Q4: Total closed tasks
SELECT assignment, COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE close_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY assignment
```

Resulting table should be

```
Group | Q1+Q3 | Q2+Q4
```

Note that in each query number of rows (groups) can differ, e.g. no tasks were opened in the specific period, but some tasks were closed, this should still be counted

Thanks!

Comment: Are `assigned_group` and `assignment` the same? Could you give a concrete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right in thinking that to get the total of Opened Incidents and Tasks you need to join Q1 and Q3 (assuming `assigned_group` and `assignment` are valid for the join)? If so then the following sub-selects will return you the total count of open incidents

```
SELECT Incidents.IncidentCount + Tasks.TaskCount AS TotalOpenIncidents ,
       COALESCE(Incidents.assigned_group, Tasks.assignment) AS Group
FROM (
    SELECT assigned_group, COUNT(*) AS IncidentCount 
    FROM incidents 
    WHERE open_time BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY assigned_group ) AS Incidents INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT assignment, COUNT(*) AS TaskCount
    FROM tasks 
    WHERE issue_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY assignment) AS Tasks ON Incidents.assigned_group = Tasks.assignment
```

You need to do the same for Q2 and Q4 to get the count of closed

Comment: Hi, this is almost great :), but I need group names too. And if there are no rows for this group in first subquery, but there are rows in the second one, the group still must be present in the final result

Comment: Thanks again! Can I use `full outer join` to make a unified table and then `isnull()` to substitute `0` instead of `null`? Like `select IncidentGroup, isnull(IncidentsCount,0)+isnull(TasksCount) from (...) as Incidents full outer join (...) as Tasks on Incidents.IncidentGroup = Tasks.TaskGroup

Comment: Yes a 'full outer join' would return data from both `Incidents` and `Tasks`, the inner join in my example would remove rows which were not present in both sub-queries

Answer (score 0):

To stick this kind of data together you either use a 'full outer join' or `UNION ALL`. Here's the `UNION ALL` method:

There are ways to refactor this query to be much simpler. If you are interested I can show you further or you can try it yourself. For example you only need 2 queries inside the Z subtable.

The `UNION ALL` method stops double counting occurring if your join columns are not unique (although in your case this is not a problem)

```
SELECT assigned_group, SUM(Closed) As Closed, SUM(Opened) As Opened
FROM
(
SELECT assigned_group, COUNT(*) As Closed, 0 As Opened
FROM incidents 
WHERE open_time BETWEEN '2014-01-01     00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY assigned_group

UNION ALL

SELECT assigned_group, 0 As Closed, COUNT(*) As Opened
FROM incidents 
WHERE close_time BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY assigned_group

UNION ALL

SELECT assignment, 0 As Closed, COUNT(*) As Opened
FROM tasks 
WHERE issue_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY assignment

UNION ALL

SELECT assignment, COUNT(*) As Closed, 0 As Opened
FROM tasks 
WHERE close_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY assignment
) Z
GROUP BY assigned_group,
```